# Remove the end of a list based on the start of another list

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I want to be able to check if the ending chunk of `list1` is present at the start of `list2`. After that I want to delete one of the chunks from any of the lists, merging both into a third list (sequentially, `list1` + `list2`).

```
var list3 = list1.Something(list2); 
//Returns 0,1,2,3 instead of 0,1,2,1,2,3
```

There's another problem, one list can be smaller than the other, such as:

```
0,1,2,3 <-- 2,3,4 = 0,1,2,3,4
5,6     <-- 6,7,8 = 5,6,7,8
```

And of course, both lists can be different:

```
0,1,2   <-- 5,6,7 = 0,1,2,5,6,7
[empty] <-- 1,2   = 1,2
```

Is there any method provided by .Net Framework that allows me to do that?
If not, could you help me create one?

The end and start can only "kill" each other if they are sequentially equal.
Example, if `list1` ends in 1,2 and `list2` starts with 2,1 they are not equal.
So, `Distinct()` is not helpful.

---

My use case:

```
private List<int> Cut(this List<int> first, List<int> second)
{
    //Code

    return new List<int>();
}

internal List<int> MergeKeyList()
{
    var keyList = new List<int>() {0, 1, 2};
    var newList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};

    return keyList.InsertRange(keyList.Count, keyList.Cut(newList));
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you think you can at least post the skeleton code required to do this?

Comment: Why did not msdn not suggest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx to you?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm still trying. :/

Comment: That's fine - show us what you've tried. Also, do you think you can at least post the skeleton code required to do this?

Comment: Also, your description "union of both lists without any repeated values between the end of one and the start of the other" seems to be too general. I assume if you started with `1,2,1` and `2,1,3` that you want `1,2,1,3`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Exactly.

Comment: @NickeManarin - Then "union of both lists without any repeated values between the end of one and the start of the other" doesn't adequately describe your problem as repeated values are allowed.

Comment: @Enigmativity Indeed. I'll change that.

Comment: I have an answer for you. Can you please post the skeleton code required to do this so that I can pop my answer in?

Comment: @Enigmativity Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    var keyList = new List<int>() {0, 1, 2};
    var newList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};

    var result = keyList.Cut(newList);
}

public static class Ex
{
    public static List<int> Cut(this List<int> first, List<int> second)
    {
        var skip =
            second
                .Select((x, n) =>  new { x, n })
                .Where(xn => xn.x == first.Last())
                .Where(xn =>
                    first
                        .Skip(first.Count - xn.n - 1)
                        .SequenceEqual(second.Take(xn.n + 1)))
                .Reverse()
                .Select(xn => xn.n + 1)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        return first.Concat(second.Skip(skip)).ToList();
    }
}
```

`result` becomes:

[image: result]

Also:

```
{ 0, 1, 2 } & { 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 } => { 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 0, 1, 2, 1 } & { 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 } => { 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 }
```

Comment: That's it. I just need to treat empty lists. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Would be much more efficient with `for` loops .. but whatever:

```
keyList.TakeWhile((_, i) => !keyList.Skip(i).SequenceEqual(newList.Take(keyList.Count - i)))
       .Concat(newList)
```

Comment: Works with empty lists.

Comment: Very clever! Much better than my answer.

Comment: @Slai Congrats for the sleek code! (Btw, the second example does not work if one of the lists is empty, it returns and empty list)

Comment: ah yes, because zip doesn't compare the counts. I'll revert back to the original. It can probably be a bit shorter by avoiding the `!`, or MoreLINQ